# Remove data label if less than a value

Tags: excel, vba

I have datalabels I've applied to a chart and now I am trying to remove those lables that are less than 1%. Here is what I have -

```
Dim cht As Chart

Set cht = ActiveChart


If Range("B8") < 0.01 Then
    cht.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.Delete
End If
```

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong, but all the data labels are removed. Do you know why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are removing the DataLabels for the entire series in this code.

What you need to do is remove the DataLabel for the specific point on the series.

This should do it:

```
Dim cht As Chart

Set cht = ActiveChart

If Range("B8") < 0.01 Then
    cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Delete
End If
```

`SeriesCollection(1)` is the first series in the chart. `Points(1)` is the first point on the chart. Adjust as needed for your code.

Comment: Can you explain what the (1) signifies in the SeriesCollection(1)?

Comment: What would it mean to change to SeriesCollection(2)? Thanks

Comment: @user1813558 -> I wrote it in the answer. `(1)` is the first series collection ... think data range...  so `(2)` is the second series, or data range.